# How to customize the delete button when UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to change the color and the text of the button when `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`, how can I do that? Here's how I call the method for deleting a cell :) Thanks!

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
        [self.tasks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the docs for `UITableViewDelegate` for the method you can implement to provide a different label. There is no standard way to change the color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is the following:

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Set NSString for button display text here.
    NSString *newTitle = @"Remove";
    return newTitle;

}
```

The method call to accomplish this is found in the [Apple iOS Dev Docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_26)

Honestly, I would NOT change the color - the Apple HIG (Human Interface Guidelines) would likely recommend the color stay a consistent red to make sure users don't have a different expectation for your app's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can custom your cell. And then, add UISwipeGestureRecognizer for this cell on method cellforRowatindexPath like this:

```
//custom delete button on cell comment
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellWasSwiped:)];
[swipeRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft |
                                   UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
```

Implement cellWasSwiped function:

```
- (void)cellWasSwiped:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
//edit your custom button delete in here.
.....
 [self.tableView commitEditingStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```